# How to retrieve identifiers dynamically in AWS appConfig start configuration session?

Tags: amazon-web-services, app-config

Previously, I was able to retrieve data from appConfig by using the variables that were hardcoded in config.ts.

Here is part of the config.ts:

```
//Used for appConfig
export const APP_CONFIG_APP_NAME = 'tableName';
export const APP_CONFIG_APP_IDENTIFIER = 'actual Identifier was written here';
export const APP_CONFIG_ENV_IDENTIFIER = 'actual Identifier was written here';
export const APP_CONFIG_PROFILE_IDENTIFIER = 'actual Identifier was written here';
```

And in my app-config-client.ts, I was passing in those variables in the StartConfigurationSessionCommand:

```
import { AppConfigDataClient, StartConfigurationSessionCommand,GetLatestConfigurationCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-appconfigdata'; 
import { APP_CONFIG_APP_IDENTIFIER, APP_CONFIG_ENV_IDENTIFIER, APP_CONFIG_PROFILE_IDENTIFIER, APP_REGION } from '../../../config';


const client = new AppConfigDataClient({ region: APP_REGION }); 

export async function getToken(): Promise<string> {
  try{
        const getSession = new StartConfigurationSessionCommand ({
            ApplicationIdentifier: APP_CONFIG_APP_IDENTIFIER,
            EnvironmentIdentifier: APP_CONFIG_ENV_IDENTIFIER,
            ConfigurationProfileIdentifier: APP_CONFIG_PROFILE_IDENTIFIER, 
            });

        //console.log('Seding getSession command...');
        const sessionToken = await client.send(getSession);
        //console.log('Received session token: ', sessionToken);
        const initialConfigurationToken = sessionToken.InitialConfigurationToken;

        //console.log(initialConfigurationToken);
        return initialConfigurationToken || "";
       // return sessionToken.InitialConfigurationToken || "";
      } catch (err) {
            console.error('Error retrieving session token: ', err);
            throw err;
          }
}
```

What I want to do is instead of using those variables, I want to retrieve the identifiers dynamically, straight from appConfig. This is because When I run in staging or prod environments, the identifiers will be newly created in the infrastructure which will cause error eventually.

I am thinking maybe using arn might work but I'm not sure how do implement it. If there is a different/better way, would love to know.